# How to horizontally center an img in a narrower parent div

Tags: css

I need to center images that will be wider than the parent div that contains them. the parent div is a fixed width and has the overflow set to hidden.

```
<div style='overflow:hidden; width:75px height:100px;'>
    <img src='image.jpg' style='height:100px;' />
</div>
```

I must use an image as the child element because I need to resize the thumbnail dimensions and cannot rely on background-size since it is not supported on older versions of mobile safari which is a requirement. I also cannot use javascript for this, so it must be a css solution.

One more thing to note is that widths will vary between images, so I can't just use absolute positioning on the child element at a hard-coded offset.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

for posterity, I've just found out that this can be accomplished on the older versions of mobile safari by using

```
-webkit-background-size:auto 100px;
```

of course, the background will be set as usual using 50% for left positioning. If you need this to work on another browser, the accepted solution is probably the best, but since this question was related to the iphone, this solution is a little cleaner.

Comment: So you want the middle of the image to be shown in the parent div with an equal amount on each side not being shown?

Comment: yes, exactly. like if you took a picture fame and centered it over a larger photo before you cropped the photo for framing. but I'm only concerned about the horizontal positioning as the heights of parent and child will match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How adverse are you to extra markup?  Also, is there a max size for the images?  For example, if your max image width is 225px then you could try:

```
<div class="frame">
  <div>
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>

.frame {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.frame > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5075px;
  width: 10225px;
  text-align: center;
}
.frame img {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

A fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/bW4xD/

Comment: this would work if i could predict the image width. but these are just random profile images uploaded by users :/ For example, if the source image is, 150x200 and the image height is set to 100px, the width will scale proportionately to 133px. if it's 130x300, then scaling the height to 100px will result in a width of 230px. See the problemo?

Comment: Is there no limit on the images that a user can upload?  You could even set the inner div to `width: 10225px` and `left: -5075px`.

Comment: In that case set the height on `.iframe img` to `100px;`.  I've update  my answer and fiddle to match.  Note the larger (original) size of the final image.

Comment: oh, i see what you're doing. actually, that first solution worked fine. i just need to make sure that the inner div uses a width that will always be bigger than the image it contains, right? if so, very clever!

Comment: That's way more complicated than my answer. :P

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't using a background image still work? You shouldn't need to resize it. 
Does something like this make sense? http://jsfiddle.net/QHRHP/44/

```
.container{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:400px;
 border:2px solid #000;  
 height:250px;
 background:url(http://placekitten.com/800/250) center top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: i have to resize it because of retina display. i'm using images that for instance are approx 200px tall, but displaying them in a 100px container. using this approach, there's no blurryness.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you said you need to resize the buttons themselves! For what it's worth I ran into the icon blurriness issue the other day and opted instead to just use different background images  when the retina display is being used. Example: @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)

Comment: yeah, i'm probably going to go that route, but since this was the only thing that would require a second css file, I was just hoping to find a way to do this without the need for that. I may also just take a server-side approach as well. a few options available, but nothing as clean as i'd like, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know the width of the div and the width of the image, you can simply do some math.

Let's say the div is width 200px and the image is width 300px:

```
div.whatever {
    width: 200px;
}
img.someImg {
    left: -50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

We know that since the width of the div is 200 pixes, then 100 pixels will be cropped from the image. If you want to center the image, then 50 pixels be hidden past the boundaries of the div on either side. Thus, we set the left position of the image to -50px.

Example (knowing the image size): http://jsfiddle.net/7YJCD/4/

Does that make sense?

If you don't know the image size or the div size, you can use javascript to detect these values and do the same thing.

Example (not knowing the image size, using jQuery javascript): http://jsfiddle.net/K2Rkg/1/

Just for reference, here's the [original image](http://bettafootwear.com/CrownYourFeet/shop/modules/editorial/images/store-banner-45-forest-onion-blunt.jpg).